# type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<CloseObservations>'

Tags: asynchronous, flutter, dart, future

I'm very new to dart and i am countering an issue with a function that suppose return a `List<CloseObservations>` and not a `Future<dynamic>` and i couldn't figure out why my function do not return the correct type.

This is my function :

```
 getData(BuildContext context) async {
    List<CloseObservations> closeObservationData = new List();
    WorkSiteState state = BlocProvider.of<WorkSiteBloc>(context).state;
    List<Stage> stages = state.workSites[state.currentIndex].stages;
    for (Stage stage in stages) {
      String stageName = stage.name;
      int closeNumber;
      try {
        for (Plan plan in stage.plans) {
          for (Observation observation in plan.observations) {
            if (!observation.open) {
              closeNumber++;
            }
          }
        }
      } finally {
        closeObservationData.add(CloseObservations(stageName, closeNumber));
      }
    }

    return closeObservationData;
  }
```

I hope the explanation of my problem is clear, if not tell me.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Can you give more context on what your method is doing? My guess is part of what your code is doing is executing an asynchronous function (since you added an async keyword to the method). Due to this, the type returned is a Future. If you want to deal with a Future, please look [here](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await).

Comment: thank you for your help, i fixed my issue by just remove the async

Answer (score 1):

You should explicitly specify return type of your function:

```dart
Future<List<CloseObservations>> getData(BuildContext context) async {
...
```

Async functions always return *Future* (there's also *FutureOr*, but you shouldn't return it - that's bad practice). If you don't need it to return *Future*, make it synchronous by removing *async* keyword and changing return type to *List*.